# My php in my HTML is making my page go off set?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to set up an upload area on my site but when ever I load the page everything goes off set but when I remove the php in my HTML it goes back to normal. No idea as to why its doing this. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();  
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
        $allowed = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $name = $_FILES["UploadFileField"]["name"];
        $tmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
        $type = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
        $newName = "Image Attachment.jpg";
        $types = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($ext,$types)){
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, "UPLOADS/$newName");
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.</b></p></font>';
            $loadingimage = true;
        }

        else {
            if(!$tmp){
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No document has been selected.</b></p></font>';
            }

            else {
                echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Uploaded document was an incorrect extension type, please use ".jpg", ".jpeg", or "png" only.</b></p></font>';
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        header( 'Location: Review.php' );
    }

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){   
        if (file_exists("UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg")) {
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION COMPLETE: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Image no longer available</b></p></font>';
            unlink('UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg');
            $loadingimage = false;
        }

        else{
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No image available for Deletion</b></p></font>';
        }
    }   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Attach Image</title>

        <link href="CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
        <script src="JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body link="black">
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
        <div id="borderDiv">
            <div id="navDiv">
                <div id="backNavDiv">   
                    <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="white"><p align="right"><b>&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Log Out</b></p></font></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="headerDiv">
                <p>Attach Image</p>
            </div>                


            <div id="loginBtnDiv">
                <div id="uploadAreaDiv">
                    <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                    <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
                    <input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload"/>
                    </form>     
                </div>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="delete" id="delete">
                    <input id="delete" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>

                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logoDiv">
        <img src="IMAGES/Logo.png">
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You echo things before you start your html, that's why

Comment: How is it offset? vertically or horizontally? Maybe because of the whitespace between closing php tag and html tag. As a side note always `die();` or `exit();` after `header('location:...');` EDIT, yep as @YannChabot  pointed out, the php produces output before the document start

Comment: you're simply ASSUMING the file upload was performed and succeeded, simply assuming that the move succeeds, you're simply assuming that your deletion succeeds, yada yada yada. That's a lot of BAD assumptions.

Comment: I suggest to concatenate `?>` and `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Sometimes white-spaces and newlines make troubles as @andrew mentioned. Also, have you tested it in more than one browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you're echo things outside the body tag! Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
ob_clean();session_start();

if (isset($_GET['logout'])){
    session_destroy();  
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    header( 'Location: Review.php' );
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Attach Image</title>

    <link href="CSS/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="CSS/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <script src="JAVASCRIPT/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body link="black">

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['delete'])){   
    if (file_exists("UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg")) {
        echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION COMPLETE: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Image no longer available</b></p></font>';
        unlink('UPLOADS/Image Attachment.jpg');
        $loadingimage = false;
    }

    else{
        echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>DETLEION FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No image available for Deletion</b></p></font>';
    }
}  
if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
    $allowed = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    $name = $_FILES["UploadFileField"]["name"];
    $tmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
    $newName = "Image Attachment.jpg";
    $types = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(in_array($ext,$types)){
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, "UPLOADS/$newName");
        echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Your document has now been uploaded and is ready to send.</b></p></font>';
        $loadingimage = true;
    }

    else {
        if(!$tmp){
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">No document has been selected.</b></p></font>';
        }

        else {
            echo '<font size="3"><p align="center"><b>UPLOAD FAILED: </font><font color="#000000" size="3">Uploaded document was an incorrect extension type, please use ".jpg", ".jpeg", or "png" only.</b></p></font>';
        }
    }
}
?>    

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="borderDiv">
        <div id="navDiv">
            <div id="backNavDiv">   
                <a href="index.php?logout"><font color="white"><p align="right"><b>&nbsp;&lt;&nbsp;Log Out</b></p></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="headerDiv">
            <p>Attach Image</p>
        </div>                


        <div id="loginBtnDiv">
            <div id="uploadAreaDiv">
                <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
                <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
                <input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField"/>
                <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload"/>
                </form>     
            </div>

            <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="delete" id="delete">
                <input id="delete" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>

            <form action="AttachImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileForm" id="FileForm">
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="logoDiv">
    <img src="IMAGES/Logo.png">
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you redirect after output? (`header("Location...")`)?

Comment: @cale_b No, you can't send headers once the output has begun

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate your HTML and PHP into thier own files. Use Javascript to run you PHP files seperate from eachother and call actions when needed.

**Here is an example of how this works**

*This example is a search-and-fill function. It's not specific to your problem but you should be able to see to logic.*

The Javascript function `formFill()` is called using `onkeyup` in the HTML input field. Using AJAX, Javascript makes a call to a seperate file (in this case a PHP file that runs a database query) and outputs the contents where you have specified (ie. `document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="formFill(this.value, 'lot')" name="lot_number"/>
<div id="lot"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
//find & fill forms with onkeyup values 
function formFill(search,x) {
       if (search.length == 0) { 
          document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = "";
          return;
       } else {
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                   document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
               }
           }
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "/forms/pull/"+ x +".php?q=" + search, true);
          xmlhttp.send();      
         }
     }
```

**PHP**

```
$s_sql="SELECT lots.lot_number
            FROM lots
            WHERE lots.lot_number LIKE '".$_REQUEST["q"]."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$s_sql);
$s_arr = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// Output
echo isset($s_arr) === false ? '' : $s_arr[0];
?>
```

This PHP query "displays" data using `echo`, because the entire file will be executed and shown to the user.